# Оптимизация скорости по PageSpeed на cms wordpress

Tags: wordpress, оптимизация, pagespeed-insights

Подскажите, как можно избавиться от этого противного пункта в pagespeed?
"Уменьшите влияние стороннего кода":
[image: j]
Пробовал загружать код через 2 секунды (отложил), но это не правильный вариант для метрик и аналитик, т.к. не вся аналитика приходит. Возможно есть какие-то решения готовые или намекните куда копать? Мучаюсь пол года, думаю день настал :)

Comment: Не обращать внимание на эти цифры  гуглофекера. На ранжирование и пр они не влияют. Единственное что стоит сделать - загружать их асинхронно и в последнюю очередь. Но только внешние ресурсы!

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте хранить скрипты на вашем сервере и периодически обновлять их по крону

Comment: можно попросить вас статейку как скачать сторонний скрипт и обновить его кроном?

Comment: @ВиталийБриль [вот пример](http://vasilenko.info/pagespeed-cache/)

Comment: а я не понимаю зачем минусуют ответ? Вижу как выход в этой ситуации